# Uninitalized String Offset

Tags: php

I have written a class in php that is supposed to intake a formula with unknown numbers (an example formula would be x+y) and replace those numbers (x & y) with numbers inputted by the user (and passed to this class). My class looks like this:

```
                        <?php
        class formula
        {
            //declarations
                private $form="";
                private $variables="";
                private $values="";
            //end of declarations

            public function __construct($f, $vars, $vals)
            {
                $form=$f;
                $variables=$vars;
                $values=$vals;
            }

            public function getEquation()
            {
                //declarations
                $curChar="";
                $varCount=0;
                $charCount=0;
                $formulaChar=array();
                $i=0;
                $equation="";
                $size=strlen($this->form);  //number of characters in $form
                //end of declarations

                while($i<$size)
                {
                    $curChar=substr($this->form, $i);
                    $formulaChar[$i]=$curChar;
                    $i++;
                }

                while($charCount<$size)
                {
                    $varCount=0;
                    while($varCount<strlen($variables))
                    {
                        if($formulaChar[$charCount]==$variables[$varCount])
                        {
                            $formulaChar[$charCount]=$values[$varCount];
                        }
                        $varCount++;
                    }
                    $charCount++;
                }

                $charCount=0;

                while($charCount<count($formulaChar))
                {
                    $equation.=$formulaChar[$charCount];
                    $charCount++;
                }
                return $equation;
            }

        }
    ?>
```

For testing purposes, I created a page that passed some dummy values to the class, and then wrote the results to the screen:

```
        <?php
        include("formula.php");
        $formula="x+y";
        $variables=array("x", "y");
        $values=array(1,2);

        $test=new formula($formula, $variables, $values);
        echo $test->getEquation();

    ?>
```

When I run it however, I get an error saying I have an uninitalized string offset on line 65 ($equation.=$formulaChar[$charCount];). What exactly does that mean, and how do I fix it? I am guessing that I did something incorrectly with the array, but I am not 100 percent sure.

Comment: : Please accpet your answers. So It will be helpful to get solution for other's facing same problem. Also use cast votes for good answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are working with strings.  in PHP, concatenation is done with the ., i.e.

```
$equation .=$formulaChar[$charCount];
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I will update the code in my post

Comment: I debugged it.  it is because $formulaChar is an empty string

Comment: why are you using global form?  If you are using private variables, in a class you can just refere to them as $this->form

Comment: $formulaChar is used as an array. Its values are assigned in the first loop

Comment: so if you do that, and change strlen($variables) to count($this->variables) since the $variables you are passing in is an array, it will work.  I can you show you the working code if you need.

Comment: yeah, but is wasn't getting initialized as an array because this line was breaking -> $size=strlen($form);  you weren't using global correctly so it was whole chain reaction

Comment: follow my suggestions.  i have it working on my local machine right now.

Comment: Can I get the working code from you? I must have missed something. Thanks so much!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8808/discussion-between-cityonhill93-and-thescientist)

Comment: update your code in your post.  do you know how to use $this-> in php?

Comment: i didn't get the answer?  lame

Comment: i don't konw, it wasn't this morning when I checked back in.  maybe you had it confused with another similar answer.  no worries really, i just like my rep to go up, lol

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add `$equation` and `$formulaChar[$charCount]` then seems `$formulaChar[$charCount]` have string value.You should cast it in `int`.

Like below:

```
$equation+=(int)$formulaChar[$charCount];
```

If `$formulaChar[$charCount]` is char string and you want to concat with `$equation` then use "." instead of "+"

```
$equation.=$formulaChar[$charCount];
```

Edit:

It's due to initialization is not OK. You should initilize `$formulaChar` as `array()` not as string

Comment: initilize $formulaChar as array() not as string

Comment: That got rid of the error, but now my test page is not displaying anything...don't you love debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. It will take your sample input and return:

1+2

```
<?php
class formula
{
    //declarations
    private $form="";
    private $variables="";
    private $values="";
    //end of declarations

    public function __construct($f, $vars, $vals)
    {
        $this->form=$f;
        $this->variables=$vars;
        $this->values=$vals;
    }

    public function getEquation()
    {
        $equation = $this->form;
        foreach ($this->variables as $index => $letter) {
            $equation = str_replace($letter, $this->values[$index], $equation);
        }

        return $equation;
    }

}

$formula="x+y";
$variables=array("x", "y");
$values=array(1,2);

$test=new formula($formula, $variables, $values);
echo $test->getEquation();
```

Comment: Thanks man, we actually figured it out. We probably did the same thin as you did though.